# Не учитывать пустое поле Edit Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

У меня на форме 4 поля Edit.

**Как исправить код так что бы:** если в **Edit1** есть текст а в **Edit2, Edit3, Edit4** нет текста (то есть они пустые), то их значение не учитывалось программой.

Поскольку в моем коде пустые edit учитываются программой и **программа удаляет еще и пробелы.**

```
var
  s: string;
  toDelete: TStringList;
  iDelete: integer;        
begin
  toDelete := TStringList.Create;
  toDelete.Add(Edit1.text);
  toDelete.Add(Edit2.text);
  toDelete.Add(Edit3.text);
  toDelete.Add(Edit4.text);

  ........................................................................
  for iDelete := 0 to toDelete.Count - 1 do
  begin
    s := StringReplace(s, toDelete[iDelete], '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    s := StringReplace(s, '  ', ' ', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  .........................................................................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```
  if Trim(Edit1.text) <> '' then toDelete.Add(Edit1.text);
  if Trim(Edit2.text) <> '' then toDelete.Add(Edit2.text);
  if Trim(Edit3.text) <> '' then toDelete.Add(Edit3.text);
  if Trim(Edit4.text) <> '' then toDelete.Add(Edit4.text);
```

Comment: Kromster, Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @Татьяна пожалуйста, не отвечайте комментариями типа "спасибо", они не несут ценной информации для других посетителей. Лучшая благодарность - стрелка вверх, галка принять, и то что вы стали чуточку умнее )

Comment: Я, поняла и в преть буду соблюдать эти правила. А умнее я стала :) благодаря вашей критике + подсказкам. Так что испытываю к Вам только уважение.